# Keep form data when form is loaded a second time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, file-upload

I have a from that does two things.

1. Gets user text input.
2. Users can select an image or upload their own.

Problem occurs when user uploads their image.

The file field must submit the information to upload the image. It does all works.

But when the form is shown with the uploaded image, the text the user entered is gone.  I understand that the instance variables won't keep the data.

How can I make this work so the text is not lost?
Must I use AJAX?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using form helpers for a model (e.g. form_for :somemodel), or are you using normal form_tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using form_for,

```
# your_controller.rb
def new # method where you show the form
  @some_model = SomeModel.new(params[:some_model])
end

# new.html.haml - i like haml
- form_for @some_model do
  ... # all your inputs (they will be pre-set if you submit the form and it stays in new method
```

if you are using form_tag

```
# new.html.haml
- form_tag do
  = text_field_tag :some_attribute_name, params[:some_attribute_name]
  = select_tag :another_attribute_name, options_for_select(['option1', 'option2', 'and so on'], params[:another_attribute_name])
```

so depends on what you using, choose the respective way ;-) hope this helps =)

HOWEVER

i think the image should be submitted together with the form and saved together, i.e. it shouldn't be a separate process, unless of course you are talking about the form is saved and you are redirecting to an edit page... either way, both methods should work =)